# How to validate button type submit in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<input type = "submit' name="submit" value="Log In">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Log in </button>
```

For input type submit, I write if ($this->input->post('submit') and then validation rules in controller. But it is not working with button type="submit". Is there any other code for button type??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the button doesn't have a value set against which to check. Try this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="some value, any value">Log in</button>
```